# Doing things after redirect when specifik rule is failing - Laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I've got a registration-form that is posting to a controller which validates the request.

```
    // Validate request
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'email|required|unique:users,email,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL',
        'zipcode' => 'digits:5|numeric|exists:zipcodes,zipcode,lat,NOT_NULL',
    ]);
```

I'd like to do things if the email already is taken (unique), rather than just send an error-message back (only for unique, not other errors).

What I want to do in the end is to open a modal after the redirect back to previous page (where the form is).

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I suppose your problem is not validating, but you want to open a modal after the redirect, right? Please be specific in your in title and question.

Comment: Thats right, but just for the 'unique'-rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can [create custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules) and try to do your stuff in a closure:

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        // Do your stuff.

        return $value == 'foo';
    });
}
```